# What exactly is meant by the term "electron-electron correlation"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, terminology

What exactly is meant by the term **electron-electron correlation** in quantum mechanics of many-electron systems?

Comment: Can you provide some more context?

Answer (score 4):

It is the correlation effect originating from the electron-electron interaction.

The simplest approximations for electronic structure in a many-electron system is the so-called one-electron approximation corresponding to neglect the Coulomb electron-electron interaction term in the Hamiltonian of the system. Consequently, the electronic Hamiltonian becomes separable into a sum of single-electron Hamiltonians, and the total wavefunction is a product (or better, an antisymmetrized product) of one-electron wavefunctions. By re-introducing the electron-electron interaction, such a simple structure of the wavefunction should be modified by introducing terms that take care of the correlations induced by the interactions.

Comment: Doesn't the antisymmetrization itself (in absence of interaction) link the fate of one electron with the fate of the others? In other words, will a system of noninteracting fermions be uncorrelated?

Comment: I think it usually means correlations beyond the bare minimum (antisymmetrization).

Comment: @mithusengupta123 That's the reason I wrote *...that takes care of the correlations induced by the interactions*. There is a correlation induced by the antisymmetry which is a different story. Hartree-Fock approximation takes care of the correlations induced by the antisymmetry, but lacks the electron-electron correlations we are speaking about.